# In my oracle database, one tablespace gives out of space alert frequently even am adding space, How to know the cause?

Tags: sql, oracle, sysdba

In my oracle database, one tablespace gives 'out of space' alert frequently even am adding space, How to know the cause?

Intially I created tablespace with size 1GB, now it's size 4GB.

How to know the reason, when am querying for used object for that perticular tablespace form dba_segments.. it is giving only segment names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use dba_segments to find what is taking up the space:

```
select tablespace_name, sum(bytes)/1024/1024 MB from dba_segments group by tablespace_name order by tablespace_name
```

This lists the tablespaces and their usage.

```
select owner, sum(bytes)/1024/1024 mb
from dba_segments
where tablespace_name = 'SYSAUX'
group by owner
order by sum(bytes)/1024/1024 desc, owner
```

This lists how much space a user id taking in your tablespace.
Normally alerts fire for a reason so ignoring them might not be the smartest thing to do.

You could of course zoom in to the objects of a particular user and repeat this over time to find which object is growing. I leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem that you describe here is the Tablespace Space Threshold. You can get your current threshold settings via (also have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/schema.htm#ADMIN014)):

```
SELECT * FROM dba_thresholds
WHERE object_type = 'TABLESPACE' AND object_name = <Your tablespace>;
```

In my case that gives me:

```
METRICS_NAME:             Tablespace Space usage
WARNING_OPERATOR:         GE
WARNING_VALUE:            85
CRITICAL_OPERATOR:        GE
CRITICAL_VALUE:           97
OBSERVATION_PERIOD:        1
CONSECUTIVE_OCCURRENCES:   1
INSTANCE_NAME:            database_wide
OBJECT_TYPE:              TABLESPACE
OBJECT_NAME:              null
STATUS:                   VALID
```

You can modify your thresholds or deactivate them altogether via the `DBMS_SERVER_ALERT.SET_THRESHOLD` method. For example, to deactivate the threshold on my system I use:

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SERVER_ALERT.SET_THRESHOLD(
   metrics_id              => DBMS_SERVER_ALERT.TABLESPACE_PCT_FULL,
   warning_operator        => DBMS_SERVER_ALERT.OPERATOR_DO_NOT_CHECK,
   warning_value           => '0',
   critical_operator       => DBMS_SERVER_ALERT.OPERATOR_DO_NOT_CHECK,
   critical_value          => '0',
   observation_period      => 1,
   consecutive_occurrences => 1,
   instance_name           => NULL,
   object_type             => DBMS_SERVER_ALERT.OBJECT_TYPE_TABLESPACE,
   object_name             => NULL);
END;
/
```

By querying DBA_THRESHOLDS again I now have:

```
METRICS_NAME:             Tablespace Space usage
WARNING_OPERATOR:         DO NOT CHECK
WARNING_VALUE:             0
CRITICAL_OPERATOR:        DO_NOT_CHECK
CRITICAL_VALUE:            0
OBSERVATION_PERIOD:        1
CONSECUTIVE_OCCURRENCES:   1
INSTANCE_NAME:            database_wide
OBJECT_TYPE:              TABLESPACE
OBJECT_NAME:              null
STATUS:                   VALID
```